# KeepAlive directive in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I included this directive in the root .htaccess file:

`KeepAliveTimeout 3`

Now I am getting this error message

"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, admin@mydomain and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Why? Can anybody help me with this, we do want to reduce the connection time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks it is not supported. That [directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout) is supported from version 2.4.3 and up. Check you Apache version.